# the following package have unmet depnedencies?

Tags: apt, dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Can someone please help me with these errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libreoffice-base-core : Depends: ure but it is not going to be installed
libreoffice-calc : Depends: ure but it is not going to be installed
libreoffice-common : Depends: ure but it is not going to be installed
libreoffice-core : Depends: ure (>= 3.5.4~) but it is not going to be installed
libreoffice-draw : Depends: ure but it is not going to be installed
libreoffice-gnome : Depends: ure but it is not going to be installed
libreoffice-gtk : Depends: ure but it is not going to be installed
libreoffice-impress : Depends: ure but it is not going to be installed
libreoffice-math : Depends: ure but it is not going to be installed
libreoffice-writer : Depends: ure but it is not going to be installed
python-uno : Depends: ure but it is not going to be installed
synaptic : Depends: libept1.4.12 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libvte9 (>= 1:0.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
uno-libs3 : Depends: ure but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I don't know how to fix this, `sudo apt-get -f install` is also not working and I can't update using both terminal and update manager.

Answer (score 1):

What did you tried to install it broke dependencies?

to remove a package misconfigured or improperly installed can run the following

```
sudo aptitude purge $(dpkg -l|grep ^rc|awk '{ print $2 }')
```

Comment: i"ve done sudo aptitude purge $(dpkg -l|grep ^rc|awk '{ print $2 }') on terminal but i got this error sarizan@sarizan-Inspiron-1018:~$ sudo aptitude purge $(dpkg -l|grep ^rc|awk '{ print $2 }')
[sudo] password for sarizan: 
sudo: aptitude: command not found
sarizan@sarizan-Inspiron-1018:~$

Comment: it just happens on upgrade process,im not trying to install packages or something,..

Comment: the command not found is because yo do not have aptitude , what happend when you try this command .  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: hi there,i had found the solution>sudo apt-get clean>apt-get -f install..thanks for helping everyone :)